# topologies on U(H)

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, fa.functional-analysis

There are many topologies on the algebra $B(H)$ of bounded operators on Hilbert space:
the *weak*, *strong*, *ultraweak* (also called σ-*weak*), *ultrastrong* (also called σ-*strong*), and some more...

Luckily, the weak and strong topologies agree when restricted to $U(H)\subset B(H)$.
Similarly, the ultraweak and ultrastrong topologies agree on $U(H)$.

> Is it true that the weak and ultraweak topologies agree when restricted to
>    $U(H)$?

---

**Definitions:**
A generalized sequence $a_i$ is *weak*ly, *strong*ly, *ultraweak*ly, *ultrastrong*ly convergent if:
• $\langle a_i\xi,\eta\rangle\to\langle a\xi,\eta\rangle\qquad \forall \xi,\eta\in H$

• $a_i\xi\to a\xi\qquad \forall \xi\in H$

• $\langle (a_i\otimes 1)\xi,\eta\rangle\to\langle (a\otimes 1)\xi,\eta\rangle\qquad \forall \xi,\eta\in H\otimes \ell^2(\mathbb N)$

• $(a_i\otimes 1)\xi\to (a\otimes 1)\xi\qquad \forall \xi\in H\otimes \ell^2(\mathbb N)$,

 respectively.
 Here, $H\otimes \ell^2(\mathbb N)$ denotes the Hilbert space tensor product of $H$ and $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: I am not sure how you interpret the tensor. Could you please elaborate this point?

Comment: Thank you pm: it's the Hilbert space completion of the algebraic tensor product. I edited the question.

Comment: Okay, I did not look carefully enough ξ  is an element of the tensor, I thought there was some identification l2(N)⊗H≅H  going on, nevermind that one. But writing $\xi = \xi_1 \otimes \xi_2$, do we not get $< (a \otimes 1) (\xi_1 \otimes \xi_2), (\eta_1 \otimes \eta_2)>= <a \xi_1, \eta_1><\xi_2, \eta_2>$, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces. But that would just be scalling?

Comment: @pm: You're right. But don't forget that an element of $H_1\otimes H_2$ is typically not of the form $\xi_1\otimes \xi_2$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The weak and ultraweak topologies coincide on bounded subsets of $B(H)$: see section 3.5 in Pedersen's book "C*-algebras and their automorphism groups".

Comment: They even coincide on the whole unitball, if I read my lecture notes correctly.

Comment: @Marcel: The unit ball is a bounded subset of $B(H)$, so you're not really saying anything different.

Comment: Yeah, I should read again before I post a comment ;) 
