# Is unitary group paracompact?

Tags: gn.general-topology, harmonic-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5891) Martin Schottenloher notices that the unitary group $U(H)$ of a separable Hilbert space $H$ is metrizable in the *strong operator topology*. As a corollary (see [R.Engelking, 5.1.3](http://www.heldermann.de/SSPM/SSPM06/sspm06.htm)), it is [paracompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space) (when $H$ is separable). I wonder

> if $U(H)$ is paracompact for an arbitrary (not necessarily separable) Hilbert space $H$ in the *strong operator topology*.

P.S. This continues the discussions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839450/compactness-of-unitary-group), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347247/in-what-topology-is-the-unitary-group-of-a-unital-c-algebra-locally-compact), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65669/topologies-on-uh) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328037/interesting-examples-of-non-locally-compact-topological-groups), but I must say that I don't even understand why $U(H)$ is not locally compact in the infinite dimensional case.